# Как ввести значения с клавиатуры в VS code в окне "выходные данные" для дальнейшей работы с ними?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Я новичок в VS code. Мне необходимо ввести значения с клавиатуры для дальнейшей работы с ними (на языке С++). Я установила расширение "code runner" для запуска кода, но не могу в окне  "выходные данные" печатать что-то с клавиатуры.

Answer (score 0):

Переключите вывод на терминал: `"code-runner.runInTerminal": true`, тогда при запуске будет использоваться именно терминал в котором есть и ввод и вывод. Если надо чтобы побыстрее запускалось, то смените дефолтный PS на CMD: `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"`

Необязательно это прям в файле настроек делать, просто в строке поиска параметров вводите название и появится этот пункт с подсказкой.

Answer (score 0):

В visual studio code в левом нижнем углу нужно открыть управление > параметры. В меню поиска написать run code configuration и поставить галочку в поле run in terminal.